# Проблема в регулярном выражении

Tags: php

Есть строка "#1104, #1104, #1108 geg787 , 894654" необходимо написал регулярку, которая проверяет наличие такого символа # перед числами. Реализовал это на js,как такую же написать на php

```
str="#1104, #1104, #1108 geg787 , 894654"
re = /#(\d+)/ig
found = str.match(re)
```

Comment: Точно так же, только ключ `g` лишний.

Comment: @PinkTux, если не сложно напишите....

Comment: `/#(\d+)/i`. Или вам вслух зачитать главу из учебника про PHP и регулярные выражения? Sorry, это не ко мне, а, например, в гугл, или сюда: http://www.php.su/preg_match

Comment: В чём именно у вас возникают трудности при написании этого регулярного выражения для PHP?